# Updating Large Json Files to Mongo

Tags: json, mongodb, scrapy

I'm having trouble updating large json files to mongo. I perform a:

```
with open('one.json') as f:   data = json.load(f)
```

And then iterate through the length of data document by document. When I try running this on an EC2 instance, it gets killed since it run's out of memory. I'm trying to see if I can iterate through this file one document at a time. Its the results of a scrapy scraping job. Here's a sample output of a json file with only 4 entries to see how the json is laid out:
[
{"ID" : "1"},
{"ID" : "2"},
{"ID" : "3"},
{"ID" : "4"},
]
How can I iterate through this one document at a time. such as only ID=1 is processed, then read next etc.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly: you're putting the whole file in memory, which is causing memory problems on the server.
A simple solution is to just ready the json-file line by line. The following should work if you just have multiple json-lines in your file:

```
with open('one.json', 'r') as input_file:
    for input_line in input_file:
        # insert line into mongodb
```

Comment: the insert line into mongodb, how do I transform that line into a json obj first?

Comment: you can just use `json.dumps(input_line)`